# Regular expression misinterpreted in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I created the following regular expression: `^C_WEBSHOP_(?!_UL)` I'm trying to match a field against it, but neither of the following keywords seem to work: `REGEXP_LIKE`,`REGEX`,`REGEXP`,`LIKE`,`RLIKE`. The script stops execution. Any idea?

I'm trying `REGEXP_LIKE(table_name,'^C_WEBSHOP_(?!_UL)')`
and
`table_name REGEXP '^C_WEBSHOP_(?!_UL)'`

Error message: `Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`

Comment: <table_name> or <field_name> ?

Comment: `table_name` definately. It's from ˙information_schema`

Comment: provide sample table and data if possible

Comment: There's no problem with the data. There's problem with MySQL misinterpreting the working Regex. (The regex has been tested to match the table names manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the cause of this error was that MySQL does not yet support negative lookaheads in regular expressions. The only workaround is to query everything and filter this using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally you will need parameterised queries or mysql_real_escape_string after that quoting, to stop the backslashes being misinterpreted as MySQL's non-ANSI-standard string literal escapes.